# One-To-Many relationship with additional table and extra column. How to represent it in Java class?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm working on Calorie Counter Application. After logging in, each user will only have access to their meals.

I have a database like below:

[image: Database schema]

I'll display all information like the template below.

| Meal 1 |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chicken breast | 100g | 130kcal |
| Apple | 200g | 100kcal |
| Tomatoes | 300g | 30kcal |

| Meal 2 |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chicken breast | 100g | 130kcal |
| Apple | 200g | 100kcal |
| Tomatoes | 300g | 30kcal |

**User class:**

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "users")
    public class User {
    
        private int id;
        private String username;
        private String password;
        private int age;
        private String email;
        private Gender gender;
        private List<Meal> meals;
    
        public User() {
        }
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id")
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        @Column(name = "username")
        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }
    
        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }
    
        @Column(name = "password")
        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
    
        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
    
        @Column(name = "age")
        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }
    
        public void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }
    
        @Column(name = "email")
        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }
    
        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
    
        @Column(name = "gender")
        public Gender getGender() {
            return gender;
        }
    
        public void setGender(Gender gender) {
            this.gender = gender;
        }
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
        public List<Meal> getMeals() {
            return meals;
        }
    
        public void setMeals(List<Meal> meals) {
            this.meals = meals;
        }
    
        private enum Gender{
            MALE,
            FEMALE
        }
    }
```

**Meal class:**

```java
        @Entity
        @Table(name = "meals")
        public class Meal {
        
            private int id;
            private LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
            private User user;
            private List<MealFoodProduct> mealFoodProducts;
        
            public Meal() {
            }
        
            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            @Column(name = "id")
            public int getId() {
                return id;
            }
        
            public void setId(int id) {
                this.id = id;
            }
        
            @OneToMany(mappedBy = "foodProduct")
            public List<MealFoodProduct> getMealFoodProducts() {
                return mealFoodProducts;
            }
        
            public void setMealFoodProducts(List<MealFoodProduct> mealFoodProducts) {
                this.mealFoodProducts = mealFoodProducts;
            }
        
            @Column(name = "created_at")
            public LocalDate getDate() {
                return date;
            }
        
            public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
                this.date = date;
            }
        
            @ManyToOne
            @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
            public User getUser() {
                return user;
            }
        public void setUser(User user) {
            this.user = user;
        }
    }
```

**FoodProduct class:**

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "food_products")
    public class FoodProduct {
    
        private int id;
        private String productName;
        private Double proteins;
        private Double fats;
        private Double carbohydrates;
        private Double calories;
    
        public FoodProduct() {
        }
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id")
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        @Column(name = "product_name")
        public String getProductName() {
            return productName;
        }
    
        public void setProductName(String productName) {
            this.productName = productName;
        }
    
        @Column(name = "proteins")
        public Double getProteins() {
            return proteins;
        }
    
        public void setProteins(Double proteins) {
            this.proteins = proteins;
        }
    
        @Column(name = "fats")
        public Double getFats() {
            return fats;
        }
    
        public void setFats(Double fats) {
            this.fats = fats;
        }
    
        @Column(name = "carbohydrates")
        public Double getCarbohydrates() {
            return carbohydrates;
        }
    
        public void setCarbohydrates(Double carbohydrates) {
            this.carbohydrates = carbohydrates;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return productName;
        }
    
        @Column(name = "calories")
        public Double getCalories() {
            return calories;
        }
    
        public void setCalories(Double calories) {
            this.calories = calories;
        }
    }
```

**MealFoodProcuct class**

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "meals_food_products")
    public class MealFoodProduct {
        
        private Meal meal;
        private FoodProduct foodProduct;
        private double weight;
    
        public MealFoodProduct() {
        }
    
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "meal_id")
        public Meal getMeal() {
            return meal;
        }
    
        public void setMeal(Meal meal) {
            this.meal = meal;
        }
    
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "food_product_id")
        public FoodProduct getFoodProduct() {
            return foodProduct;
        }
    
        public void setFoodProduct(FoodProduct foodProduct) {
            this.foodProduct = foodProduct;
        }
    
        @Column(name = "food_product_weight")
        public double getWeight() {
            return weight;
        }
    
        public void setWeight(double weight) {
            this.weight = weight;
        }
    
    }
```

My questions:

1. Is it correct way to connect these classes?
2. What should be an **ID** in MealFoodProduct class?

Comment: You should use [composite identifier](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite) for the `MealFoodProduct`

Comment: There are three possible options: 1) `EmbeddedId` / `@Embeddable` 2) `@IdClass` or 3) Hibernate does allow composite identifiers to be defined without a "primary key class" via multiple @Id attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use composite identifiers with `@IdClass` for the `MealFoodProduct` entity.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "meals_food_products")
@IdClass( MealFoodProductPK.class )
public class MealFoodProduct {
    
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "meal_id")
    public Meal getMeal() {
        return meal;
    }

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "food_product_id")
    public FoodProduct getFoodProduct() {
        return foodProduct;
    }

    // ...
}

public class MealFoodProductPK implements Serializable {

   private Meal meal;
   private FoodProduct foodProduct;

   public MealFoodProductPK(Meal meal, FoodProduct foodProduct) {
      this.meal = meal;
      this.foodProduct = foodProduct;
   }

   public MealFoodProductPK() {
   }

   //Getters, setters, equals, hashCode are omitted for brevity
}
```

Additional details see [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite-nonaggregated).

P.S. Other parts of your mapping look good.